# Laravel mix 5.4 versioning

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, webpack

Siguiendo la documentación de Laravel, dice que es innecesario mantener versionados los css y js en desarrollo el cual me parece correcto. Entonces hice lo siguiente, tengo en webpack.mix.js:

```
     mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
        .js('resources/assets/js/mol.js', 'public/js')
        .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
        .sass('resources/assets/sass/mol.scss', 'public/css')
        .sass('resources/assets/sass/login.scss', 'public/css');

        if (mix.inProduction()) {
            mix.version();
        }
```

En el .env tengo

> APP_ENV=production

y para compilar hago npm run production, pero no me funciona. De esta forma no agrega el hash a los js y css.

Ahora si agrego .version al final de mix.js(...).version(); ahi si me anda, pero tanto en modo development como en modo production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tengo entendido que en ciertos casos el mix que está en webpack.min.js no es exactamente una instancia de Mix, por lo cual hay que hacer la comparación con la configuración:

```
if (mix.config.inProduction) {
    mix.version();
}
```